# How do i call a function of node js in vanilla js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

i have a node js function -

```
const BpmnModdle = require('bpmn-moddle')
var bpmn = function () {
  var bm = new BpmnModdle()
  console.log(bm)
}
module.exports = bpmn
```

I want to call this function in pure vanilla js.

What i have tried so far-
i have created a fileData javascript file in which i have tried to call bpmn function

fileData.js

```
function createData(xml, node) {
  var bp = bpmn();
  console.log(bp)
}
```

i have tried to bundle both in webpack. Where my webpack config file is

```
module.exports = {
    entry: [
      './javascript/examples/editors/js/bpmn.js',
      './javascript/examples/editors/js/app.js',
      './javascript/examples/editors/js/deletes.js',    
      './javascript/examples/editors/js/fileData.js',
      './javascript/examples/editors/js/jsonData.js',
      './javascript/examples/editors/js/new.js',
      './javascript/examples/editors/js/open.js',
      './javascript/examples/editors/js/save.js',
      './javascript/examples/editors/js/saveas.js',
      './javascript/examples/editors/src/js/mxClient.js',
      './node_modules/bpmn-moddle/dist/index.js'
    ],
    output: {
      path: __dirname,
      publicPath: '/',
      filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.js$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          use: {
            loader: "script-loader"
          }
        },
        {
          test: /\.css$/,
          use: [
            {
              loader: "style-loader"
            },
            {
              loader: "css-loader",
              options: {
                modules: true,
                importLoaders: 1,
                localIdentName: "[name]_[local]_[hash:base64]",
                sourceMap: true,
                minimize: true
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  };
```

I am unable to call this function in pure js and i am getting an error saying
"bpmn is not defined".

Comment: What do you mean "pure vanilla JS"? Vanilla JS is a langauge, not a technology, so: what are you trying to run it in? Do you mean you're trying to run it in the browser?

Comment: yes in the browser.I just want to access a function written in node js in my pure javascript program

Answer (score 1):

Include the `bpmn` module in the calling function file and then call it.

In your code your are not telling the webpack about the `bpmn` module dependency.

To add the module in the webpack bundle you have to add the `module` in the calling function file/Module.

**Example**

Create the file structure like this.

[image]

Create these file and paste the code.

**webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require('path');
module.exports = {

    mode: 'development',
    entry: './src/index.js',
    output: {
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    },

};
```

**Package.json**

```
{
    "name": "Stackoverflow",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "",
    "main": "index.js",
    "scripts": {
        "build": "webpack --config webpack.config.js"
    },
    "keywords": [],
    "author": "",
    "license": "ISC",
    "dependencies": {
        "bpmn-moddle": "^6.0.0"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "webpack": "^4.41.5",
        "webpack-cli": "^3.3.10"
    }
}
```

**src/index.js**

```
import bpmn from './bpmnModdle.js';
function createData(xml, node) {
  var bp = bpmn();
  console.log(bp)
console.log('Module called');
}

createData();
```

**src/bpmnModdle.js**

```
import BpmnModdle from 'bpmn-moddle';
var bpmn = function () {
    var bm = new BpmnModdle();
    console.log('bm', bm)
    console.log('From inside the module');
    return 'exported'
}
export default bpmn;
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <script src="../dist/bundle.js"></script>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>

</body>

</html>
```

Run `npm install` 
Run `npm run build`

Open the index.html file in the browser

> I am using `ES6` module as the `bpmn-moddle` package doesn't support `commanJS` module system.

Comment: my main goal is just  to access a function written in node js in my pure javascript program.so what should i do for this?

Comment: It should be available after the webpack bundle.

Comment: You have to add your code in the main bundle using webpack, otherwise you will not able to access the code.  Modules are encapsulated it's not available globally. If you want to use it then you have to `require` it and then you can use.

Comment: i dint get you? i mean i have already added module.exports = {
    entry: ['./javascript/examples/editors/js/bpmn.js',]} in my webpack.config.js. When i try to require bpmn js in the fileData.js ,it says require is not defined!! please help?

Comment: Yes correct, but you have to write your dependent code like this.  `const bpmn = require('./bpmnModdle.js');
function createData(xml, node) {
  var bp = bpmn();
  console.log(bp)
}`

. So it tells webpack that I need this module. then webpack will give access to this module.

Comment: You have to transpile first with webpack, you cannot use this syntax directly in browser.

Comment: when i added  'const bpmn = require('./bpmnModdle.js'); function createData(xml, node) { var bp = bpmn(); console.log(bp) }' in fileData.js it says require is not defined?

Comment: During the webpack transpilation ?

Comment: how do you transpile with webpack can u give me a reference or documentation?

Comment: thank you !! can you post the working code in your answer itself?

Comment: Please check the code and let me know, if this is helpful