# I have 2 javascript files. How to bundle them into one file and enclose all code in one enclosed scope?

Tags: javascript, .net-core, scope, bundle, minify

Say i have 2 files
helpers.js
index.js

Loading helpers.js will create global variables. I don't want that

I want one file.js that looks like

```
(function () {
    helpers.js code
    index.js code
})();
```

1. Is this even possible?
2. Can I do it with .NET Core Bundle And Minify?

Answer (score 0):

You can use webpack to bundle the js code.

Or just use  [ES6 modules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) to modularize your code.

> Note: Not all browsers support ES6 modules. For that you need `babel`.

Please refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59728063/how-do-i-call-a-function-of-node-js-in-vanilla-js/59728247#59728247) answer. I have explain this in detail .